# Giving users scheduling privileges

Tags: scheduling, privileges

I have some code which uses [`sched_setscheduler`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) from `sched.h`

```
sched_param sched;
sched.sched_priority = 70;
sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_FIFO, &sched);
```

However, this function will fail unless I run the application with `sudo`.  I'd rather not run the application with `root` privileges.

Is there a way for me to grant a user or process access to this function without granting full root permissions?

-- Edit --

**derobert** gave a [great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455091/272848) about using capabilities. In `postinst`, I simply add:

```
setcap cap_sys_nice+ep /path/to/myapp
```

The problem here is:

```
bin$ ./myapp
./myapp error while loading shared libraries: libmylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The program loses the ability to dynamically load libraries from `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or (in my case) other libraries pointed by `rpath`.  This appears to be [intended behaviour](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=448594).  Is there a way around this?

I've tried `setcap cap_setpcap+ep myapp` then using `prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP, CAP_SETPCAP);` before I do any of the dynamic loading, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, though it's a little weird and exposes a hole in the OS.

During `postinst`, I:

```
cp $(which chrt) bin/chrt
setcap cap_sys_nice+ep bin/chrt
```

Then in the code, I launch a process with:

```
bin/chrt -o -p 70 getpid()
```

The hole we just exposed is that anyone who uses this version of `chrt` can do it without admin privileges. Since I'm running this is a very controlled target environment, I'm okay with that hole, but I wouldn't recommend it who doesn't have control over their target environment.

Comment: I just ended up doing stuff like `sudo chrt 99 ionice -c1 nice -n -20 sudo -u myuser ./myprogram options...`

Answer (score 2):

Changing your scheduler & priority should only need the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability; see the [sched(7)'s Privileges and resource limits](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/sched.7.en.html#Privileges_and_resource_limits). You'll probably also want to look at the manpage for [`sched_setscheduler`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/sched_setscheduler.2.en.html), which mentions sched(7).

There are a few ways to give your program that capability; the easiest is probably [setcap](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libcap2-bin/setcap.8.en.html):

```
# setcap cap_sys_nice=ep /usr/local/bin/your-program
```

That works similarly to set-user-id, but is much more limited (as it only gives the one capability). Of course, CAP_SYS_NICE effectively gives the program permission to hang the system (by eating all CPU time with realtime tasks).

Other ways include using a runs-as-root wrapper (that drops all other permissions) or elevation using, e.g., RealtimeKit/PolicyKit.

(For more information on capabilities, I suggest starting with [capabilities(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/capabilities.7.en.html)).

Comment: When I use `setcap`, My program ignores its custom rpath and can't load some specific `*.so`files.  This seems to be [intentional](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=448594). How can I drop these capabilities when I am done with them so I can dynamically load the appropriate *.so files after that?